# Number of variables and local scopes in use?

Tags: pine-script

When writing a Pine Script script in Tradingview, you sometimes run into one of the 'limits' of Pine Script, such as:

- maximum number of variables (max 1000 ?)
- maximum number of local scopes (max 500 ?)
- maximum number of Securities calls (max 40?)

These are the ones that I know of. Perhaps there are even more.

My question: is there a way to check the current use of your script of these parameters?
So, the number of variables and local scopes currently in use. Just to know 'where you are' with your script and how much room there is to add more code.
The number of Securities calls is fairly easy to check. Variables is another matter ....

Just wondering .... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to request that metadata afaik.

Comment: I think so too. But you never know. Pine Script has so many features that I still have to learn .... Maybe some day...